# Changing path of flvplayer from timeline in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dynamic, flv

I can get the videos to play using the flvplauer component, but I'm having a little trouble figuring out if and how to dynamically change the path of the flvplayer while running through a timeline.

If I can do something like `mc.changeFLVPath` that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where you call the function from, you should be able to do the following

```
function playFLV(url:String):void
{ 
    playerInstanceName.source = url;
    //or mc.playerInstanceName.source = url;
}
```

Comment: Sometging told me it was a property...thanks for the directikn.  Gonna try it tonight...thanks for such a quick response too!

Comment: Giving you a ONE UP from here cause my rep is too low to vote up, thanks again lol